# A* pathfinding in Slick2D: how do I make an enemy move?

Tags: java, image, move, path-finding, slick2d

I am trying to create a 2D Tower Defense. I am creating it in Java and using the Slick2D library. I am using the A* pathfinder for the enemies. The pathfinder works perfectly and can print in the console the correct way. But I am having trouble implementing the pathfinders x and y coordinates on to the enemies x and y coordinates. I want the enemy images to move accordingly to the x and y that the pathfinder finds. 
For the pathfinder; it uses a 2D array of 10x10.

```
AStarPathFinder pathfinder = new AStarPathFinder(map, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, false);
    Path path = pathfinder.findPath(null, (int)startPosX, (int)startPosY, endPosX, endPosY);
    int length = path.getLength();

    public enemy() throws SlickException {
    }


    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        map = new LoadMap();
        System.out.println(length);
    }




    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException, InterruptedException {
      if (curr_x != endPosX && curr_y != endPosY) {
              for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  curr_x = path.getX(i);
                  curr_y = path.getY(i);

                  System.out.println("Move From: " + (int) prev_x + "," + (int) prev_y + ".");
                  System.out.println("Move To: " + (int) curr_x + "," + (int) curr_y + ".");

                  if (curr_x - prev_x > 0) { //RIGHT
                      System.out.println("RIGHT");
                      startPosX = startPosX + delta*speed/300;

                  } else if (curr_x - prev_x < 0) { //LEFT
                      System.out.println("LEFT");
                      startPosX = startPosX - delta*speed/300;

                  } else if (curr_y - prev_y > 0) { //DOWN
                      System.out.println("DOWN");
                      startPosY = startPosY + delta*speed/300;

                  } else if (curr_y - prev_y < 0) { //UP
                      System.out.println("UP");
                      startPosY = startPosY - delta*speed/300;

                  }
                  prev_x = curr_x;
                  prev_y = curr_y;
                  System.out.println("------------------");
                  if (curr_x == endPosX && curr_y == endPosY) {
                      System.out.println("Done!");
                  }
              }
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        e1.draw(startPosX*w,startPosY*w,w,w);

        g.drawString("posX "+startPosX,100,100);
        g.drawString("posY "+startPosY,100,120);

    }
```

If anybody can push me in the right direction, I'd be so happy.
Thank you.

Comment: The enemie's render() function is supposed to be called by someone. What class is rendering the screen?

Comment: Don't you just set the enemies coordinates to the x and y given by the pathfinder? Sorry I don't think I understand

Comment: @alex440 , the enemy class is being used in the main class and is being rendered correctly. That's not the issue. The issue is the position of the `e1`. 

@MCMastery That's the whole point I want the x and y coordinates to be 'fluent'. As it is right now, the for-loop runs through it's x amount of times and then sets the position of the enemy image.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. It seems like you attempt to draw your e1 at the coords startPosX, startPosY, and you say the coords are correct and the rendering it is not an issue. So what's the issue?

Comment: This problem is not trivial. Determining the path is the first step however you need to move your entities accordingly, this heavily depends on your game and your game architecture. You basically need to take the closest coordinate out of your determined path to your entity and move your entity towards this coordinate until its even. You repeat this until your path is empty. In the meanwhile you always need to update your path in case the map or entities are chaning it's position. It's hard to tell where your exact problem is due to missing information of your architecture

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this based on the assumption that your enemy has already found it's "Path". Let's say it's a List (ArrayList, if preferred) that contains all of the tile coordinates (i.e. the correct "path"), or tiles. Now for each "update step" or tick in the game, you want to use A* to find the path for the enemy and update it based on the current enemy's grid position, or tile. The enemy would have a "target" tile, which would be the first tile in the array of the current calculated path. You would just take the x and y of that tile and in the update function for the enemy, you would update its x and y in relation to the latter tile.

For example, if my enemy was at (0, 0), and wants to get to (5, 5), I would use the A* algorithm to get the list of tiles for the shortest route. On each update, I would make my enemy move to the "target" or next tile in that path list from A* until we reach the latter tile. Rinse and repeat.